# Warning to use method with care

Tags: java

For example I have a method (not safety to use, may cause spam/unexpected behaviour, etc) which allows you to manually start the mailing. I know how it works, and what can i expect. But if other developer will try to use it, he might will not sure what is method for (he might use it for testing new feature with real emails). What mechanisms are there to warn the developer except comments?

Maybe annotations? Are there any examples? Should such methods even exist?

```
     /**
     * <b>IMPORTANT!!!!!</b>
     * <p>BETTER DON'T USE UNTIL U'RE NOT SURE WHAT IS THIS METHOD FOR. In bad scenarios may cause spam to our users.</p>
     * <p>If u want to use it to test sending to users, make sure that {@link SenderService} method {@code sendToUsers} will send
     * messages to not real users emails. You should change value for <b>emailTo</b> variable before.</p>
     *
     * Uses GET request to start sending emails to users manually.
     *
     * @return response with status code and body wrapped in ResponseEntity
     * @throws Exception if the retry has been manually terminated by a listener.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendToUsersManually() throws Exception { 
        log.info("Starting manual sending for users.");
        scheduledMailSenderService.sendToUsersOnSchedule();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Manual sending for users finished.");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer, but you could always allow the method only if some system property were present. That would at least ensure no one would execute it without a proper initialization, and if they try to initialize it, then that would mean they know what they are doing.

Comment: You could put "danger" (or some other signifier) in the method name itself. Even if a developer fails to read the docs, they might notice the method name.

Comment: This seems to be not so much a method (although, of course, it is that, too) but rather a web service. To this, entirely different mechanisms might apply, depending on the framework being used, e.g. the comment will be entirely invisible to the user of the API, as will be any log output, or the name of the method itself. So, is this actually about developers using the method, or users using the API?

Comment: About developers. This method from REST controller. And this method is useful to check changes without waiting for the scheduled start.

Answer (score 1):

I would not warn a developer, not to use a method, but I would exactly explain in the comments, when and how to use the method and what errors you could run in. That is the best way, to to "warn" someone. Why a method, that is so unsure, that someone should be warned to use it, except from the commentary or standard annotations like `deprecated`?